# Why isn't this conditional statement working with NSUserDefault?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit, nsstring, if-statement

I'm having a problem getting one of my conditional statements to display data correctly. Here is the code I'm working with:

```
    NSUserDefaults *pickerDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *myString = [pickerDefaults stringForKey:@"userpicker"];
NSString *string = @"Name1";

NSLog(@"%@",myString); //This prints out Name1
NSLog(@"%@",string);   //This also prints out Name1 

if (myString == string) {

    [pickerArray addObject:@"Name Other"];

}

else {
return;
}
```

I can't get this if statement to add that object to the UIPicker eventhough both strings are equal to each other. However, if I change it to not equal to != then it display's the object in the UIPickerView. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To compare string objects, don't use their pointer values, but compare using

```
[string isEqualToString:myString]
```

Comment: Works Perfect Now, Thanks. You get answer due to being the first one to respond with the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (myString == string) // Wrong : It compares address of two NSStrings

if ([myString isEqualToString:string]) // This compares values of NSStrings
{
}
```